# Importing Processing sketch in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, processing

*Is it possible to import processing sketch in visual studio?*

***What I would like to do is to create a simple animation in Processing and use it in visual studio as a background in windows forms application or WPF?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can't do this because Processing Sketches are actually Java programs (usually running OpenGL for the rendering). Visual Studio does have a Java library/support for Windows Forms or WPF last I checked. It may be possible with some third party addins or extensions.

Now, if your aim is to have the cool Processing sketch you've made appear in a Windows application, there are a number of ways to go about it. You can export the Processing Sketch as a Windows application.

If you need Windows Forms/WPF etc. for other functionality (sounds like you do) then:

1. If the animation is static, export it/save it as a .mp4 or .avi and use a WPF / Windows Forms control to display the animation.
2. If the animation is interactive and must respond to user clicks etc., then it would be easier to develop the sketch in something like [Win2D](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Introduction.htm), though I realise that is a lot more work.

Comment: @Mystia Stephen's answer is very accurate and well explained(+1). Your best bet would be if someone else already ported the Processing API to WPF and as far as I know this port doesn't currently exist. If if's a simple animation, the WPF graphics api should do. One hacky thing that comes to mind is maybe use a webview from WPF and use a JS port of Processing, like [p5.js](p5js.org) for example (just as long as it doesn't make things to complicated). I'd stick to the native WPF graphics apis